# Существует ли архитектура процессоров с русским набором команд?

Tags: архитектура, железо, кириллица, машинный-код

Собственно сам вопрос в заголовке: существует ли или может разрабатывается какая-либо архитектура процессоров с Ассемблером (названиями команд) на русском языке? И где об этом можно почитать подробнее?

P.S. Вопрос именно про **существование**, а не про **необходимость**.

Comment: Вообще-то, команды процессоров не русские и не английские, а двоичные коды.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow справедливое замечание, уточнил вопрос.

Comment: Эм... Вы про асм на русском? Команды процессору передаются через дырки, если уж на то пошло.

Comment: Кажется, со времен БЭСМ-6 такой хренью больше не страдали.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос, скорее всего, так как отношение к обсуждаемой тематике меня не интересует, а интерес представляет сама эта тематика. Специально указал об этом в самом вопросе, дабы избежать обсуждения не по теме, но увы...

Comment: @edem ассемблер достаточно легко реализовать (относительно языков высокого уровня), поэтому если у кого-то была необходимость в русских мнемониках, то можно перевести на русский уже существующий ассемблер и вероятно это уже делали. Или вас интересует, когда первый ассемблер для нового машины сразу на русском создавался?

Comment: @edem Возьмите любой ассемблер для любой архитектуры и переведите команды, это займет от силы дня два. И думаю ради шутки кто нибудь наверняка это делал. А вопрос ваш сейчас звучит примерно как "существуют ли модели автомобилей, управлять которыми могут владеющие языком эсперанто"

Comment: @jfs да, сразу на русском чтобы, и не обязательно первый, а в принципе существование таких разработок интересует (не устаревших).